# Why data changed after mounted in vue 2?

Tags: vue.js

```js
<template>
  <div>
    {{testData.first}}
    <!-- The screen shows the value set by mounted. -->
  </div>
</template>
<javascript>
export default {
  data(){
    return {
      testData: {}
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    this.testData.first = 'hello';
  }
}
</javascript>
```

I understand that when mounted is called in the life cycle of 'vue', data is already defined.
I do not define the properties of **testData**.
I initially did not set a property of the **testData** when mounted is called, so I think must be visible screen at the empty value. Of course, I've already known testData isn't reactivity data.
Please explain why this phenomenon occurs.
Maybe I didn't understand Vue well.

Comment: its javascript behavior, if a javascript object doesn't have a key and you want to update its value its automatically added to object

Comment: `so I think must be visible screen at the empty value` What exactly are you trying to say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Of course, I've already known testData isn't reactivity data.

`testData` is reactive, because it's what you declared. But `testData.first` is not, because it's **NOT** what you declared. So you tell Vue `testData` is a reactive **object**, but you changed a non-existent **property**, which is a totally different story.

Therefore, if you declare it as a reactive **object**, you have to give it an **object**, totally makes sense. Otherwise, if you want to give it a property, you have to tell Vue. This can be done with the aid of Vue [$set](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/?redirect=true#vm-set).

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      testData: {}
    }
  },
  template: `<div>{{testData.first}}</div>`,
  mounted() {
    this.testData = {
      'first': 'hello'
    }; 
    //this.$set(this.testData, 'first', 'hello'); //either will work
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
</div>
```

It was the inconvenience of using the ancient VueJS 2. VueJS 3 has removed `$set` ([doc](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/global-api-treeshaking.html#affected-apis)) and worked around this. So I have a high expectation that your code will work well on Vue 3